# How to use Cucumber from SharpDevelop

Tags: c#, cucumber, bdd, sharpdevelop

I would like to use Cucumber from the .NET world and SharpDevelop seems like a good choice, but I'm not finding a good example of how to do it

Answer (score 3):

Prehaps this doesnt answer you question but we use SpecFlow for BDD which is absolutally awesome and integrates into visual studio. If you havent picked a BDD framework i would highly recommend it.

http://specflow.org/

Comment: My issue is that I want to share the tests with an environment that is already using Cucumber, so I want to be able to integrate with it

Comment: Specflow uses the same parser as cucumber so the definition language is pretty much identical.

Answer (score 3):

[SpecFlow](http://specflow.org/) is an open source project that you can use to do BDD on .NET. It [aims to be compatible with Gherkin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/976078/cucumber-alternative-for-net) which is the language used by Cucumber.

SpecFlow supports both Visual Studio and SharpDevelop. I looked at the integration with SharpDevelop and put together a post on [how to use SharpDevelop with SpecFlow](http://community.sharpdevelop.net/blogs/mattward/archive/2011/08/09/SpecFlowIntegration.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, and I might end up going with SpecFlow (article linked looks good btw). I will keep this open a bit more to see if I get some more help on the Cucumber side of things