# ASP.NET equivalent of rspec or cucumber for behavior driven testing

Tags: asp.net, ruby-on-rails, cucumber, bdd, nspec

I am currently working on a ASP.NET project and I was wondering if there is an equivalent behavioral testing framework for ASP.NET, something similar to rspec and cucumber in Rails.

Comment: This question has already been asked and answered:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/976078/cucumber-alternative-for-net

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The linked question in the comments deals with a cucumber alternative ([SpecFlow](http://www.specflow.org/specflownew/) being the most popular), for an RSpec equivalent, there is [NSpec](http://nspec.org/).

Comment: I also found this great answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307895/what-is-the-most-mature-bdd-framework-for-net/5586525#5586525

Answer (score 0):

There is also MSpec aka machine spec.

Github link:
https://github.com/machine/machine.specifications